# How is this visual effect called, how to do it in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects

How is it called when the carvings on a wooden or metallic surface are filled with ink while the relief is left uncover or painted resembling a shiny material. Beside, is there a common technique to accomplish this effect in Photoshop?

[image]

**Edit**

Looking for photoshop-antique-text-tutorial (thanks to Scott for his answer) I found [this](http://psd.tutsplus.com/tutorials/text-effects-tutorials/gold-old-world-text-effect/) tutorial that closely resembles the effect I want to accomplish, but I need to change the sharp Bevel & Emboss effect for a smooth transition and maybe an outer glow that darken the regions surrounding the relief.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Play around with the *Bevel & Emboss* effect in Photoshop

Quick/silly example: [image]

Answer (score 3):

In metallurgy it's called `Antiquing`.

To create a similar appearance in Photoshop, simply darken the areas you wish to appear farther recessed.

Without seeing images you are actually working with, it's difficult to give any further guidance.